# ReactJS - document not defined

Tags: reactjs

The code below does not work throwing an error that:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import App from './components/App';
import reducers from './reducers';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('.container'));
```

In Atom, it says that 'document' is not defined. When I try to run 'npm start' I get the error: Syntax error: unexpected token - underlying the Provider element.

edit: Some more information:

Yes, I have eslint set up. It underlines 'window' and underneath the error says: window is not defined.

I initially cloned this repo:
https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxCasts/tree/master/book_list/src

added some minor changes to data (it was working fine) and copied the code to another machine (excluding node_modules). Once I've copied the code to another machine I ran: npm install to install all the dependencies. It did not throw any errors so I assume all the necessary packages have been installed.

Comment: We need a lot more code than just this to figure out what's wrong. For example, what do you mean "Atom says that `document` is not defined"? Do you have a linting plugin maybe? Those likely will trigger that error because you never define `document` in the context of this file. And for that token, what does `npm start` do? What server are you running? Are you bundling things? Do you have problems installing `react-redux`?

Comment: Thanks just added some more information.

Comment: I think we need more information. The code you provided is exactly the same as the cloned one. Provide us with the stack trace, any changed code, etc.

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried to find the differences in code but could not see anything that would help and as there were only a few changes, I cloned it again and did the changes from scratch.

Comment: I don't think `document`/`window` not defined is your problem, linting err might comes from you haven't included `browser` in your "env" entry of `.eslintrc`. I'm wondering have you ever touched the `webpack.config.js` file when copying? As you at least added eslint to the original repo.

Comment: No, I didn't. Perhaps that was the reason